# intuition for continuous r.v.

Tags: probability

I understand discrete: it's a function that takes as input an element of sample space and maps it to a number; the PMF shows the list of values the r.v. takes on with their associated probability.

I just learned what a continuous r.v. is and I kind of understand it mathematically, but not intuitively. Basically, what I've learned is that it's the area under a curve for some valid PDF. So $P(a<X<b)$ is basically the area under the PDF from a to b. But that's all I know as of now and I have zero intuition behind what this actually means. I think it'll be significantly more clear as I do examples.

Here are some questions: does the domain for a continuous r.v. have the same meaning as the domain for a discrete r.v.? what I mean is that is the domain all the numbers the continuous r.v. can map to as output? that's so bizarre because that means there must exist an event in the sample space that maps to, for example, pi or $sqrt(2)$ - what does such an output even mean? Like the outputs for discrete r.v.s "made sense" to me because the output of an r.v. was sensical: e.g. number on the top of a die after rolling. but what does it mean for an event to output like pi?

also how does this relate to the idea that $P(X=k)=0$? I get mathematically that this is the "rectangle" with width zero and is therefore zero but I have zero intuition behind this.

Comment: A good example of a continuous random variable $X$: A store clerk measures the amount of time until the next customer arrives, and $X$ is the result.

Comment: It sounds like your intuition is on the right track, but you might be confused about the definition of a random variable. A random variable is not the same thing as its probability mass (or density) function. A random variable is a function whose domain is the sample space, because it's something that "takes a value" in each abstract "outcome"; its *range* is the set of possible values. The probability mass (or density) function is determined by this function combined with the probability measure associated with the sample space.

Comment: @littleO Does P(X=5) mean the probability that the next customer arrives in 5 minutes? If so, that should be probably be > 0, but P(X=k) for any k is 0 for continuous r.v.s. This is where I'm confused.

Comment: @Karl Yes, I follow that for the discrete case. I just don't follow it for the continuous case; can you explain my above comment?

Comment: @beginner Yes $P(X=5)$ is the probability that the next customer arrives in exactly $5$ minutes. And this probability is $0$. What is the chance that the next customer arrives in exactly $5.0000000000$ minutes, to infinite precision? It is certainly not likely.

Comment: You're right that if $X$ is a continuous r.v. then $P(X=x)=0$ for every value of $x$. That's exactly why the PMF isn't useful and we use PDFs instead. Imagine throwing a dart (whose tip is a single point) at a dartboard. For any given point on the board, the probability the dart lands exactly there is vanishingly small (i.e. $0$), but the probability that the dart lands in a given *region* can be nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what we can do to answer some of these questions.  Since your questions are more about the intuition than formal calculation, I'm going to be a little fast and loose with terms here.

1. Yes, the domain is (roughly) the values that the continuous RV can output.  Sometimes, we use this as an approximation for something more concrete -- say, a measurement of people's heights.  We rarely measure heights to more than the nearest half-inch, and never measure them to irrational values, but because the difference in heights between people can be so finely graded we can treat it as continuous.
2. A continuous RV is outputting something with a measure -- say, an amount of gasoline in a barrel.  The variable might give an output that happens to be 3.14159265358979323... gallons of gasoline in the barrel; the RV doesn't consider $\pi$ to be any more special than any other irrational number.  Perhaps you don't believe that measurements in the real world can be perfectly irrational -- fear not!  Refer back to answer 1, take a very close rational approximation, and be content.
3. If we have 4 equally likely outcomes, P(X=x)=0.25 for one of those outcomes.  If we have 10 equally likely outcomes, P(X=x)=0.10 for one of those outcomes.  In the case of a continuous variable, however, we have infinitely many outcomes.  If I can think of literally any number between 0 and 1, to any number of digits I wish, what's the probability that you can guess it correctly on the first try?  You can't.  Even if we assume we're just using a lot of outcomes like with the height example, consider all the heights between 4'10 and 6'10, going by quarter inches.  There are 96 outcomes in the discrete random variable case, so P(X=x)=0.0104 for each individual outcome... but there are definitely heights inbetween there, so is a continuous random variable with P(X=x)=0 really such a bad approximation?